# What is wrong with my code that sends a message when a discord bot joins a server?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot send the message like "hi guys" with discord.py whenever it joins a server. but the code that I am trying to use to send the message does not work. It doesn't show any errors however.

code: (some of the imports are for other stuff in the code)

```
import discord
import os
import random
import time
from discord import channel
from discord.message import DeletedReferencedMessage, Message
from discord.utils import find

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
        if member == client.user:
    
         await channel.send('hi guys')
```

Please tell me what is wrong so that I can get it working. (I am fairly new to coding in python btw)

Comment: The `on_member_join` event happens when some other member joins a guild, not when you join.

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_join).

Answer (score 0):

Change `on_member_join` to `on_guild_join`.

- `on_member_join`: called when a member joins the guild
- `on_guild_join`: called when the bot joins a guild

Comment: Please could you elaborate on your answer and explain it